# should I put registerDoSNOW(parallel) outside of a package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, r-package

Should I put the initialization of paralell outside of my developing package, and let the user to setup it?

Such as the following codes:

```
numCores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(numCores)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
...main body of foreach...
stopCluster(cl)
```

It seems slow when I do in this way.

Comment: I think {caret} is using something similar. What do you mean it seems slow?

Comment: Yes, as a developer you should always leave it to the end user to decide on what parallel foreach backend they want to use.  Your role as developer is to choose _what_ to parallelize, not _how_ and _where_.

Comment: Also, don't use 'snow' and 'doSNOW' unless you've got a good reason - they're deprecated in favor of 'parallel' and 'doParallel'.

Comment: @HenrikB Thanks a lot. I am also considering leaving the initialization of parallel to the end users. Since I have parallel and non-parallel versions of the program. What I am concerning is, from the users' end, they may just want to speed up the program by simply change parallel argument to TRUE. How's your feeling of it?

Comment: Rhetorical counter questions: Exactly what should `parallel = TRUE` do?  Parallelize on local machine? What about users that have access to multiple machines? ... or a high-performance compute cluster with a job scheduler?  What about packages that calls your function internally - do they now have to add a `parallel` argument and pass it down as well?  What if they disagree what `parallel = TRUE` should do.

Comment: You wrote "I have parallel and non-parallel versions of the program": Note that you now have two code basis that you need to maintain and write tests for.  This increases your maintenance burdens and the risk for bugs.  Ask yourself: "Do I really need this?"

Comment: @HenrikB Got your points. I shouldn't make it too specific such that the flexibility was restricted. LOL. Good rhetorical questions. Then what I can found good reference about developing parallel in a package?

Comment: @HenrikB In terms of "parallel and non-parallel versions", I meant to give users the choice to run the program in parallel or not, just like some packages do. How should I deal with this feature?

Comment: Q: "I meant to give users the choice to run the program in parallel or not, .... How should I deal with this feature?": A: If you use `y <- foreach(...) %dopar% { ... }` in your package, it will run sequentially by default. Users can also set it to run sequentially by setting `foreach::registerDoSEQ()`. This is at the core of Steve Weston's philosophy behind the design of foreach.  (The future framework that I develop follows this philosophy too; Developer decides _what_ to parallelize - User _how_ to parallelize)